# Import columns to existing OpenRefine project

Tags: openrefine, import-from-csv

How do I add a column from an external .csv file to an existing project?

I tried to find the solution online, but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the file you provided, I did this in less than one minute.

I had a project, with one column: [image: premier].

If you know a little Python, try Jython. **Edit Column** > **Add column based on this column** and chose *Language : Jython* like this:

[image: second]

```
import csv 
#we are going to use DictReader to transform our imported rows into dict, 
#so we can latter just refer to the column we want by its key i.e header
rows = csv.DictReader(open('/home/yourusername/Downloads/example.csv'), delimiter=",")  
for row in rows:
        return row['Comprar'] #'comprar' is the header of the column i want
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I couldn’t make it work.
How do you adapt that code to pull column “Comprar” from file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19563431/example.csv ?
Thank you.

Comment: So your line should be `rows = csv.DictReader(open('C:\ where\your file\is\ example.csv'), delimiter=",") `. Just search how to open a file on Windows in Python. Your problem is really simple to solve.