# OpenRefine columnwise scripting

Tags: openrefine

I spent some time Googling, but couldn't find anything useful.

How to select all the values of a *single column* in *OpenRefine* in a *script*?

It seems that all the operations are row-wise

In particular, I want to find highest and lowest values in a column

Answer (score 0):

Facets will give you a list of all the values in a column - so the simplest way of getting the lowest/highest values in the column is to make a facet on the column and see the resulting highest/lowest in the facet to get the answer.

However I'm not sure if this meets your criteria for selecting the values 'in a script'. By this I assume you mean you want to be able to access the lowest/highest values in a GREL expression?

You can do this, but you have to force OpenRefine to treat all the rows in project as part of a single record. The easiest way to do this is usually to add a column at the start of the project which is empty except for the first cell which contains a value.

Once you've done this you can access all the values in a column by using syntax like:

```
row.record.cells["Column name"].value
```

See also my answer to [OpenRefine - Fill between cells but not at the end of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075083/openrefine-fill-between-cells-but-not-at-the-end-of-the-list/33110054#33110054) which uses the same technique

Further explanation:

1. Create a new column at the start of your project and put a single value in the very first cell in that column
2. Switch to Record mode
   At this point you should have a single 'Record' in your project - e.g.

[image: Force single record in OpenRefine]

At this point using the syntax like row.record.cells["Column 1"].value gives you an array of all the values in "Column 1". You can then use GREL expressions to manipulate this - including sorting or comparing values.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "force OpenRefine to treat all the rows in project as part of a single record"?

Comment: Extended the answer to give more explanation

Answer (score 0):

By default, OpenRefine functionality are limited for computation. The [Stats Extension](https://github.com/sparkica/refine-stats) make basic stats per column (min, max, average, medium ...).

Comment: Looks interesting, only I am looking for a faster simpler solution

Comment: That will be the simplest. Just need to install the plugin

Answer (score 0):

A Text Facet has an nice undocumented option to gives you aggregated results in a column that you can just copy and paste.

1. Click on the "X choices" in the upper left corner of the Text Facet box.
2. This will bring up a separate dialog that contains the values along with the count of each value in that column.

(If your looking to just get ALL the values of a single column, then use Export -> Custom Tabular Exporter and then Select and Order Columns to Export by clicking on checkboxes, then click on Download tab to choose your export format and then click Download button.)

[image]
[image]